# How to test dynamodb with JMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, amazon-dynamodb

I'm relatively new to JMeter and I was wondering how one would go about load testing or performance testing on dynamodb using JMeter?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to test DynamoDB itself? According to the [Amazon DynamoDB project page](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/):

> Amazon DynamoDB is a key-value and document database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at any scale. It's a fully managed, multi-region, multi-active, durable database with built-in security, backup and restore, and in-memory caching for internet-scale applications. **DynamoDB can handle more than 10 trillion requests per day and can support peaks of more than 20 million requests per second**

So if you have a system which relies on the DynamoDB as the data tier it's highly unlikely that the DynamoDB will be the bottleneck so my expectation is that you should rather focus on your application code and if it appears that the DynamoDB is the bottleneck the only thing you will be able to do is to reach out to Amazon and explain your NFTs/ask whether it is possible to increase the performance.

With regards to the approaches, it depends on how does your application communicate with DynamoDB, ideally you need to exactly replicate the load pattern.

From JMeter perspective there are following options:

- Use [JDBC Confiration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and [JDBC Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request), in this case you will need to have an appropriate JDBC driver in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and the driver is [Magnitude Simba Amazon DynamoDB JDBC connector](https://www.magnitude.com/drivers/dynamodb-odbc-jdbc#evaluation)
- Use [Java SDKs for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/community/#java), the options are in:

  - Add the SDK .jars with all the dependencies to JMeter Classpath and use their functions from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
  - Use existing [AWS DynamoDB Sampler plugin](https://github.com/yintaosong/jmeter-dynamodb)
  - [Develop your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices) implementing the functionality you need

Comment: Thank you for this, it does make sense that DynamoDB won't be the bottleneck. How about if I had 1 million records with 10 fields each. How would I go about testing if all the records contain all the fields or they are missing some?